# How to spin and rotate in css?

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have tried spinning and sliding seperately and they work fine. But when I combine them they have an awkward combo.

http://jsfiddle.net/62RJc/268/

```
img{

    border-radius:50%;  
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: What does "awkward"  mean...what are you expecting.

Comment: there was a lot of flickering but @Aramil Rey seemed to have solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are using keyFrame, you can achieve this with transform alone.

Take a look at this:
(Also, hovering an img while its moving is not an easy task)

```css
img{
    border-radius:50%;    
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;    
}

button:hover + img {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(200px) rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>Animate!</button>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-100-9.jpg"/>
```

To make image stay where it is after animation ended:
1) Remove `button:hover + img {}` from CSS
2) Add JS

**JQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('img').css('transform', 'translate(200px) rotate(360deg)');
});
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ljdbgms/) - Element not returning to starting position!

Comment: is there anyway to stop it from rotating back?

Comment: You are adding CSS to the element only while 'button:hover' is being triggered, you should add those styles permanently with JS to make the image stay where it was after the animation

Comment: I just wanted to make it rotate and stop with a display: none. for example: it rotates, stops, then clears.